# Macro error means job name is no longer set

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins has stopped setting the job name for it's pipelines, so now the history is just a number, I can see an error in the job when it runs:

> Failed to evaluate name
> macro:org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Error
> processing tokens

I can't find any relevant plugins that affect this so I think I think this is probably due to an automatic update that's happened while I'm away (Version now Jenkins 2.401.1)

Has anyone seen this or have any idea how to fix this?